# How can I call anonymous function without using Eval?

Tags: javascript, callback, eval, anonymous-function

I have an autocomplete function with callback to return data. This autocomplete function is used by many different instances.

```
$.fn.acItem = function(callback){
  var self = this;
  $(self).autocomplete({
    (...)
    select: function(e, ui){
      // Eval for calling anonymous function (right?)
      window[callback](ui.item);
    }
  });
};
```

I'm also using namespaces

```
var Agency = {
  init: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.registerAgency.addItem();
  },

  registerAgency: {
  (...)
    addItem: function(item){
      if(!item){
        (...)
        // Initiate autocomplete on input
        $('.search-item').acItem('Agency.registerAgency.addItem');
      } else {   
        // Do something with Item
      }
    }
}

Agency.init();
```

Using `window[callback](ui.item)`works if I'm not using namespace. But with namespace, it gets a bit more complicated as [described by Jason Bunting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string).

Since different namespaces is using `acItem()`, it needs to know what function to call in the callback. But using Eval for calling anonymous function is strongly discouraged by many.

So what is a good way for doing callback on anonymous functions?

Comment: can acItem take a function as parameter ?

Comment: It's javascript, so yes, I would assume that. So I should pass the function instead of a string? Doesn't the function trigger before Autocomplete is finished?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `window[callback]()` (no quotes)?

Comment: Yeah, typo by me deceze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `window['foo']()` is *not* "eval". It's the same as `window.foo()` using different syntax, which you probably wouldn't call "eval" either.
2. The problem with this is that you expect your callback function to be a specifically named global function. But you don't have to pass functions *by name*; functions are first class objects in Javascript and can be passed directly *as values*. You actually should simply accept *a function* as callback:

   ```
   $.fn.acItem = function(callback) {
       callback();
   };
   ```

   This function accepts the callback as function and calls it. Very straight forward. You'd pass the callback like this:

   ```
    $('.search-item').acItem(function () { .. });
    // or:
    $('.search-item').acItem(this.registerAgency.addItem);
    // or, to preserve the `this` context inside the callback:
    $('.search-item').acItem(this.registerAgency.addItem.bind(this.registerAgency));
   ```

Comment: Thanks @deceze, that worked. Seems I got side railed by Jason Bunting's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `acItem` can take a function as parameter, you just have to give it like this :

```
$('.search-item').acItem(Agency.registerAgency.addItem);
```

The function will not be executed when you give it like this. You just give the function, you don't execute it.